# symfony2 FOSUserBundle custom registration form validation fails "please enter a password"

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have customized the registration form of the FOSUserBundle and I've added it to my BloggerBlogBundle, but when I try to submit the registration form it just says "please enter a password"...

this is my registrationFormType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('fname', null, array('label' => 'first name', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('lname', null, array('label' => 'last name', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('category','choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            'sport' =>'sport',
            'news' => 'news',
            'ecommerce' => 'ecommerce',
        )))
        ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your controller or routing. please provide your customized form ... did you ommit the password there or what did you do?

Comment: I've added the customized form above, password have not been ommitted.

Comment: Just to make it clear ... you provide the same password two times in your form but the form doesn't validate and has a field-error "please enter a password" ?

Comment: I think so,because i added some echo stuff in my 
"if($form->isValid())" body...but it didn't printed out.

Comment: please see my answer and accept if it resolves your issue - otherwise please leave another comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [original form](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php#L30) in the FOSUserBundle you're trying to override.

The field `password` doesn't exist in there. The field-name is `plainPassword`.

Change the name of the field in your custom form to resolve the issue.

Comment: is it that simple?:))
tnx dear nifr